# Is there analogue for this ruby method?

Tags: ruby, enumerable

Recently I've came up with this method:

```
module Enumerable
  def transform
    yield self
  end
end
```

The purpose of method is similar to `tap` method but with the ability to modify object.

For example with this method I can change order in an array in chain style:

```
array.do_something.transform{ |a| [a[3],a[0],a[1],a[2]] }.do_something_else
```

Instead of doing this:

```
a0,a1,a2,a3 = array.do_something
result = [a3, a0, a1, a2].do_something_else
```

There are also another conveniences when using this method but...

The method is very straightforward, so I guess somewhere should be the already built method with the same purpose.

Is there analogue for this ruby method?

Comment: Yes. Object#tap return self, but it is provided since 1.9.

Comment: My version returns the result of yield self i.e. the result of block not just self.

Comment: Correction: yield to self, which is in your method. You did not mention you want to return self too, and there is reason to return the block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with [`instance_eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval):

> Evaluates (…) the given block, within the context of the receiver

Example:

```
%w(a b c d).instance_eval{|a| [a[3], a[0], a[1], a[2]] }
# => ["d", "a", "b", "c"]
```

or using `self`:

```
%w(a b c d).instance_eval{ [self[3], self[0], self[1], self[2]] }
# => ["d", "a", "b", "c"]
```

Comment: Yes, it's very close to my version, but your version is slower then mine in 2.2 times.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test this now but you should be able to do something like this:

```
array= [1,2,3]
array.tap{ |a| a.clear }
```

Tap runs the block then returns self so if you can modify self in the block, it will pass back the updated array.  In my example clear modifies self in the block so the modified self is returned.

If you want this functionality, I would suggest adding a method like do_something_else! that modifies self then running it within your tap block.

Comment: For this kind of thing, you can replace `tap` with `instance_eval` and use `self`, this allows you to return a copy instead of having to mutate the original variable

Answer (score 0):

So where is the question? It all depends on how far you want to go into functional programming realm. Just read `Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!` and you will never be the same. Once you open this Pandora box it's really hard to stop and after some experimenting I wonder if I'm still writing Ruby code. Compare (using your `transform` method defined for `Object`)

```
h = {}
{:a => :a_method, :b => :b_method}.each do |k, m|
  h[k] = some_object.__send__(m)
end
h.some_other_method
```

and

```
some_object.transform(&THash[:a => :a_method, :b => :b_method]).some_other_method
```

where

```
THash = 
  lambda do |t| 
    h = {}
    kms = t.map { |k, v| [k, v.to_proc] }
    lambda do |x| 
      kms.each { |k, m| h[k] = m[x] }
    end
  end
```

So if you want to think of your objects in terms of transformations, it makes perfect sense and does make code more readable, but it's more than just `transform` method, you need to define generic transformations you use frequently.

Basically it's called `point-free` programming, though some call it `pointless`. Depends on your mindset.

Comment: The question is in the title, but I updated the question. I've tried Haskell several times but I didn't get it, i hope I will once, thanks for answer.